# bigquery python client: load_table_from_file not working with csv file

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, storage

I'm trying to append new rows in an existing bigquery table from a csv file. The csv is:

```
"sprotocol";"w5q53";"insertingdate";"closeddate";"sollectidate";"company";"companyid";"contact"
"20-22553";"DELETED";"2020-01-26;0000-01-01 00:00";"0000-01-01 00:00";"";"";"this is a ticket"
```

An this is my python function:

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.source_format = 'text/csv'
    job_config.write_disposition = bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
    job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
    job_config.autodetect = False
    job_config.schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField("sprotocol", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("w5q53", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("insertingdate", "TIMESTAMP", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("closeddate", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("sollectidate", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("company", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("companyid", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("contact", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE")
    ]
    job_config.fieldDelimiter = ';'
    job_config.allow_quoted_newlines = True

    with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
        load_job = _connection.load_table_from_file(
            file,
            table_ref,
            job_config=job_config
        )  # API request
        print("Starting job {}".format(load_job.job_id))

        load_job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.
        print("Job finished.")
    file.close()
```

I receive the following error:

```
[{'reason': 'invalid', 'message': 'Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the errors[] collection for more details.'}, {'reason': 'invalid', 'message': 'Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 55, but line starting at position:743 contains only 1 columns.'}]
```

I've tried also to remove the schema definition, but I receive the same error.
Someone can help me?

Comment: No need for file.close() at the end. with does it automatically :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three issues in the above code

1. use `field_delimiter` instead of `fieldDelimiter`

   `job_config.field_delimiter = ';'`
2. Use `DATE` instead of `TIMESTAMP` because input contains only date

   `bigquery.SchemaField("insertingdate", "DATE", mode="NULLABLE"),`
3. Double quotes are not proper

   `"20-22553";"DELETED";"2020-01-26";"0000-01-01 00:00";"0000-01-01 00:00";"";"";"this is a ticket"`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. About point 2 I have to refer to bigquery table schema (is a timestamp). About point 3 I've removed quoted fields. The problem was related on this point.

Comment: @br1 Happy that solved your issue, can you mark this as answer