# How to upload a table from a CSV file to GCP BigQuery using a Python script?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I’m new to GCP BigQuery. I would like to upload [this dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zd4hcopyarm7PvRvBDfga2_1OHRdjTzW/view?usp=share_link) to BigQuery using a Python script as follow: (I’m using this [post](https://medium.com/pipeline-a-data-engineering-resource/automate-your-bigquery-schema-definitions-with-5-lines-of-python-7a1996749718) & these [Github examples](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/tree/35627d145a41d57768f19d4392ef235928e00f72/samples/snippets) as references)

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import gdown
from pandas import read_csv
from google.cloud import bigquery
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from google.oauth2 import service_account


def create_schema(field_list: list, types_list: list):
    schema_list = []
    for fields, types in zip(field_list, types_list):
        schema = bigquery.SchemaField(fields, types)
        schema_list.append(schema)
    return schema_list


def auth():
    os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = os.getenv(
        'PATH_CREDENTIAL_GCP')
    key_path = os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        key_path, scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
    )
    client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials,
                             project=credentials.project_id,)
    return client


def bq_load(df, dataset_id: str, table_id: str, schema):
    bq_client = auth()

    dataset_ref = bq_client.dataset(dataset_id)
    dataset_table_id = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
    job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
    job_config.autodetect = False

    job_config.schema = schema

    job_config.ignore_unknown_values = True
    job = bq_client.load_table_from_dataframe(
        df,
        table_id,
        location='US',
        job_config=job_config
    )
    return job.result()


def main():

    load_dotenv()
    working_dir = os.getcwd()
    print(working_dir)

    data_path = working_dir+'/news.csv'

    df = read_csv(data_path)
    headers = features_names.to_numpy()

    types_df = df.dtypes.to_numpy()

    field_list = headers
    type_list = ["INTEGER", "BYTES", "BYTES", "BYTES", "INTEGER"]

    result = create_schema(field_list=field_list, types_list=type_list)
    dataset_id = "some_dataset_id"
    table_id = "some_table_id"

    bf_to_bq = bq_load(df, dataset_id, table_id, result)

    print(bf_to_bq)
    return 'Done!!'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

By running the prior code, I’m getting this error `google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 4, but line starting at position:0 contains only 4 columns` :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/bigquery/table_upload_bq.py", line 110, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/user/bigquery/table_upload_bq.py", line 103, in main
    bf_to_bq = bq_load(df, dataset_id, table_id, result)
  File "/Users/user/bigquery/table_upload_bq.py", line 65, in bq_load
    return job.result()
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/envs/py-3.10.7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job/base.py", line 911, in result
    return super(_AsyncJob, self).result(timeout=timeout, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/envs/py-3.10.7/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py", line 261, in result
    raise self._exception
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 4, but line starting at position:0 contains only 4 columns.
```

This is what the CSV looks like (it has 5 columns):
[image: dataset]

If someone could suggest to me how to should this problem, it would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the number of columns in CSV?  Can you provide the sample data in CSV in your question?

Comment: Hi @0x55b1E06FF Do this [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61021127/) and [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64208113/) help you?